# Set Document Mode for Website We Don't Control

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

There is a site developed by Oracle and hosted at our parent company that users at our company need access to. This site only renders properly if the Document Mode is set to IE8. Our users have Internet Explorer 10. The site meta tag is below. And no, it's not a typo. Apparently IE=100 is the same as using Edge mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" >
```

Our parent company is unwilling or unable to change it to IE-8.

We need this site to render properly. Is there a Group Policy we can deploy that would force this particular site to use IE8 for document mode? We do not want it to affect other Intranet sites. Or is there some other way of doing it on our end besides Group Policy?

One idea I had was to develop an Internet Explorer add-in that changes the document mode when visiting that site. But that seems enormously complex.

Comment: You're on Windows 7, you can't downgrade to IE8 anyway.

Comment: "Apparently IE=100 is the same as using Edge mode." Well, until IE v101... :-)

Comment: Please consider using transparent http [proxy with content rewriting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465236/python-twisted-proxy-and-modifying-content).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Internet Explorer 11 can change the document mode between 5, 7, 8, 9, and 10. I'm just looking for a more automated way to change that so it's transparent for our users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody happens across this, I never found a good solution. Since users are not good at remembering to change the document mode, I ended up creating a script using AutoIT that launches Internet Explorer, navigates them to the site, logs them in, and changes the document mode. Users are now instructed to access this site by running the AutoIT script.

If someone comes along with a better answer I'll gladly unmark this one as the answer.